# Configuring my office e mail in samsung galaxy 3

Tags: email, samsung-galaxy-apollo, exchange

Does samsung galaxy 3 have support for microsoft exchange servers . I am trying to configure my office e mail (which uses exchange server) but my phone keeps giving IOException. Any solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether Samsung includes an own solution -- but there are several Apps available on the playstore which can work with Exchange:

- [K-9 Mail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsck.k9) probably is the most popular mail app. It supports Exchange via WebDAV.
- [TouchDown for Smartphones](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nitrodesk.droid20.nitroid) is said to work very well with EAS, and syncs emails, contacts, calendar and tasks with your Android device
- [Moxier Mail (Exchange)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.emtrace.hermes) also claims to do

There are several more apps available -- but these three should get you started (well, I guess you got started meanwhile)...

Comment: Touchdown works very well (and I use it with the office's Exchange server), but it is worth noting that the app in the Play Store is a 30-day free trial that you need to buy a license for to carry on using.